# Show that the representation given by the action of $A_4$ on $\mathbb{C}_4$ by permuting vector entries is the sum of two irreducible representations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A_4$ act on $\mathbb{C}^4$ by permuting the entries of the vectors. Let $\rho$ be this representation. I wish to show that $\rho$ is the sum of two irreducible representations.

I have shown that $\rho$ has a trivial subrepresentation given by restricting to the subspace spanned by $(1,1,1,1)$. Call this subspace $A$. I also know then that there must be a $A_4$-stable subspace $A^0$ such that $\mathbb{C}^4=A\oplus A^0$ . Of course, I'm not sure how to show that restricting $\rho$ to $A^0$ even gives us an irreducible representation, nor if this information is true. I don't think this approach is good however. Based on the hints in the problem (this is an old qual problem), I think I am supposed to use: (a) the cycle structures of the elements of $A_4$, and (b) the fact that the norm of a character is $1$ if and only if it is irreducible.

I am interested in an approach which is not ad-hoc, and I would prefer something which resembles what one might consider "the standard approach" as much as possible. In particular, if you think of some smart way to show that $A^0$ is irreducible, this would be less preferred than some form of standard reasoning which will use the facts (a) and (b).

Comment: If A0 was reducible then, by Maschke, it would have a one-dimensional submodule....

Comment: @MatthewTowers I agree with what you said, but is the contradiction from that fact immediate?

Comment: No, you still have some work to do after that

Comment: Stop deleting your questions, this is really annoying https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3912046/birational-morphism-of-mathbba1-is-necessarily-an-isomorphism

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The representation of $A_4$ preserves the hermitian product, take the orthogonal of $Vect(1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: I believe that the orthogonal complement of $Vect(1,1,1,1)$ gives what I describe as $A^0$. I also agree that the representation of $A_4$ as stated preserves hermitian product. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how these two facts might be related, nor how I would achieve a solution using these two facts. Any more detail in the hint perhaps?